# How to wait that a GameObject instance has completed own Start from another GameObject instance's Start with Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two `GameObject`s like this:

```
public class GOA : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
     ... do something ...
    }
}
```

and another object that depends from the first in this way:

```
public class GOB : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    { 
     // wait GOA has terminated own "Start" life cycle
     ... then do something ... 
    }
}
```

How can I make `GOB:Start()` to wait until `GOA:Start()` has terminated?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`Start` method can be a coroutine.
You can write something like this:

```
public class GOA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool IsInitialized { get; private set;}

    void Start()
    {
        ... do something ...
        IsInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

And Here's your GOB script:

```
public class GOB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GOA aInstance;
    IEnumerator Start()
    { 
     // wait GOA has terminated own "Start" life cycle
     yield return new WaitUntil(() => aInstance.IsInitialized);
     ... then do something ... 
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to include `using System.Collections.Generic;` in GOB script.

Comment: That is what I was doing, but erroneously I put the remaining code after the "wait" in the start.

Answer (score 2):

It seeems to me that you are looking for Script Execution Order (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-MonoManager.html).
Edit-> project setting -> script Execution Order.
Use the '+' to add scripts.

Set GOA to -100 and GOB to +100. That wat GOA Will have its start method called before GOB's start method.

Comment: I already checked it, but for my understanding it is time based.

Answer (score -1):

I already had to do that thing, cascade initialisation. The trick I found was this one :

```
public class GOA : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isInitialized = false;

    void Start()
    {
        // ... do something ...
        isInitialized = true;
    }
}
```

And then, in class B, I initialize in `Update()` method. I'm using a boolean to make sure the initialisation will occur only once

```
public class GOB : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isInitialized = false;
    var a = GameObject.Find("A");

    void Update() //Update ! Not Start()
    {
        if (!isInitialized  && a.GetComponent<GOA>().isInitialized)
        {
            // initialize B...
            isInitialized = true;
        }
    }
}
```